# Reference Error only on 'age' and not on 'name'

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

```
function User(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
var user = new User('Daniel', 45);
document.write(user[name] + ' is ' + user[age] + ' years old!');
```

**I know the difference between dot notation and bracket notation.** When the above code is run in chrome console, `Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined` is shown. Since I've not declared `name`, it should throw error as `name is not defined` as it is encountered first in the code.
I logged `window.name` and `window.age` only to see "" and undefined respectively.

Thinking I might have used `name` in global scope before, I tested the same code after clearing browser history and also in a new browser, Firefox which I've never used before. The same error is shown in both scenarios.

**Does this mean that `name` is initialized to empty string by default in any browser?**

After I did `delete window.name;`, it gave error on `name`. But why would `name` be already empty string in a completely new browser. Any comments would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: 'I logged window.name and window.age only to see "" and undefined respectively' - and that didn't ring a bell? ["All String and Symbol values, including the empty string, are valid as property keys"](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type).

Comment: This not a duplicate of "JavaScript property access: dot notation cs. brackets". Please read the question: "Does this mean that name is initialized to empty string by default in any browser?" Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Ivan this is a "get up from your pc, walk for a bit, come back, look at it again, problem (hopefully) solved". Also towards the question, really, all i do is google too - give it a try: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). PS: i also tried on Node 10.0.0 and as expected, `window.name` is `undefined` there.

Comment: Indeed but this is not a duplicate of the post provided by @Nina.

Comment: @Ivan Take this as unrelated to this topic: i know some questions get closed as duplicate of something vaguely related when it takes too long to get the close votes for something else. What is related is that i don't see much value in reopening it. OLD: "As OP didn't comment, i assume he/she either found the solution by themself or read my (hopefully not inacceptably offending) comments and understood those." NEW: oops, i just remembered commenting takes 15 rep or something - a questionable rule.

Comment: see here http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#code=function%20User%28name,age%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.age%20%3D%20age%3B%0A%7D%0Avar%20user%20%3D%20new%20User%28'Daniel',%2045%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28user%5Bname%5D%20%2B%20'%20is%20'%20%2B%20user%5Bage%5D%20%2B%20'%20years%20old!'%29%3B&curInstr=5&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D which is showing reference error first name or age?

Comment: I still don't think it would be marked as duplicate: the thread "var name and window.name" is about global variables. I'm still not convinced.

Comment: @BeingSunny, Error is thrown on name in pythontutor. My question is why would name be already defined and initialized to empty string in a new browser?

Comment: please see the actual duplicate targets. name is [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and is a reserved property of window.

Comment: `window.name` is the name of the current window: "*The name of the window is used primarily for setting targets for hyperlinks and forms. Windows do not need to have names.*" from [MDN webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). So in our case it doesn't have a name: `window.name` returns a empty `String`.